# Obtaining an specific db value

Tags: php

I'm using PDO for a connection into my db. There, I have a table where I store the users. In that table I have 5 columns: id, username, password, mail and sex.

What I really want is to store in a SESSION variable, the sex of the user that has been logged in. I don't know exactly what to use, because all the examples that I've seen, are usually for printing all the results of the db into the webpage with a foreach statement, but that isn't what I want.

Actually, this is the code that I have:

```
$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', "user", "password");
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password';

$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

$statement->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$statement->bindParam(':password', $_POST['password'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
$result = $statement->execute();

if ($result) {
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    if (!empty($result)){
        $_SESSION['login'] = true;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        echo 'Hello '.$_POST['username'].', you have been connected successfully.';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Sorry, this user do not exist.';

    }
}
```

So, this is correctly working.
But now, what I want is to store the sex value from the db in a $_SESSION['sex'] variable. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add in the session after username, you have already slected from your query

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['sex'] = $result[0]['sex'];
```

You might want to remove `$result` from query execution, so this line

```
$result = $statement->execute();
```

Will be

```
$statement->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign it from the result row:

```
$_SESSION['sex'] = $result[0]['sex'];
```

You have to use `[0]` because you used `fetchAll`, which returns a 2-dimensional array of rows and columns.